# get folder path to the program in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need the  to found a folder in my application like "c:\users\programFils\myProgram\myFolder" **not** the bin folder or exe?

Comment: You need to clarify your question and correct the grammar issues.

Comment: with this Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath); I came into the bin\debug I do not whant bin folder I wahnt witout bin folder

Comment: That folder is the sandbox for your program during debugging with Visual Studio. It will be different when you publish and install your application.

Comment: I create a TXT file and I want to save him and he keeps in the BIN I'm want in a separate folder

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath).Replace(@"bin\debug\", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 7):

This code returns the folder path of the executing assembly.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are after but you can use for example `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs)` to find out some folder locations - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx